# numpy representing array of matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an array of 2x2 complex matrices that represents a transformation of a [scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix) matrix over time. For my calculations I need a way to multiply such arrays between themselves (matrix multiplication); multiply each matrix in the array by another matrix; apply a [transformation](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/tech/node98.html) to all matrices in the array.

I've tried multiple ways of doing so with the `numpy` (4 column array, array of arrays, array of matrices, list of matrices), but each of them, while providing a nice interface for some of the required functions, makes the rest very awkward.

So here's the question - what is the best way to represent such structures and how would I carry out the required transformations over them?

### examples

Initially data is in `csv` file:

```
import numpy as np
csv = np.arange(45.).reshape(5,9)
t = np.array(csv[:,0])  # time array
```

#### 4 column array

transform `csv` to 4 column array:

```
data = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [x[1]+1j*x[2],
                                      x[3]+1j*x[4],
                                      x[5]+1j*x[6],
                                      x[7]+1j*x[8]],1,csv)
```

array x matrix:

```
m = np.array([[1,0],[0,0]])
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: (x.reshape(2,2).dot(m)).reshape(1,4),1,data)
```

array x array:
would probably require a for loop and array preallocation

transformation:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [-(x[0]*x[3]-x[1]*x[2])/x[2],
                               x[0]/x[2],
                               -x[3]/x[2],
                               1/x[2]],1,data)
```

#### list of arrays

transform `csv` to list of arrays:

```
data = [np.array([[i[1]+1j*i[2],
                   i[3]+1j*i[4]],
                  [i[5]+1j*i[6],
                   i[7]+1j*i[8]]]) for i in csv]
```

array x matrix:

```
m = np.array([[1,0],[0,0]])
[i.dot(m) for i in data]
```

array x array:

```
[data[i].dot(data[i]) for i in range(len(data))]
```

transformation:

```
[np.array([[-(np.linalg.det(x))/x[0,1],
            x[0,0]/x[1,0]],
           [-x[1,1]/x[0,1],
            1/x[0,1]]]) for x in data]
```

#### array of matrices

transform `csv` to array of matrices:

```
data = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [[x[1]+1j*x[2],
                                       x[3]+1j*x[4]],
                                      [x[5]+1j*x[6],
                                       x[7]+1j*x[8]]],1,csv)
```

array x matrix:

```
m = np.array([[1,0],[0,0]])
data.dot(m)
```

array x array:
would probably require a for loop and array preallocation

```
data * data # not a dot product
```

transformation:
would probably require a for loop and array preallocation

Comment: What do you mean by array vs. matrix?  In numpy we have `ndarray` with various shapes and number of dimensions.  Stick with those where possible.  You can reshape, transpose, do broadcasted math, and matrix multiplication with them.

Comment: This needs a [mcve].  I'd suggest starting with a (n,2,2) array, and show how you'd do the various operations.  Or at least show the easy ones, and describe the problems with the hard ones.

Comment: @hpaulj added examples